# Why does my while condition not work for some conditions?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a rock paper scissors python game with water, fire, and grass. How do I get the game to end when `targetScore` is reached?

Here is the code, but when I want to play best of 3 the game keeps going.

```py
import random
choices = ["water",
           "grass",
           "fire"]
bestOf = [1, 3, 5, 7]

userChoice = ""
userScore = 0
compScore = 0
targetScore = input("Pick number to play up to (1, 3, 5, or 7): ")

while userChoice != "quit" or userScore == targetScore or compScore == targetScore:
    compChoice = random.choice(choices)
    userChoice = input("Pick either water, grass, or fire: ")
    userChoice = userChoice.lower()

    print ("The CPU called out %s and you called out %s!" %(compChoice, userChoice))
    # if the answers are the same
    if userChoice == compChoice:
        print("Tie game.")
        print("Scores: User: %d CPU: %d" %(userScore, compScore))
    # if the user beats the cpu
    elif userChoice == "water" and compChoice == "fire" or userChoice == "grass" and compChoice == "water" or userChoice == "fire" and compChoice == "grass":
        print("You win!")
        userScore += 1
        print("Scores: User: %d CPU: %d" %(userScore, compScore))
    # if the cpu beats the user
    elif userChoice == "water" and compChoice == "grass" or userChoice == "grass" and compChoice == "fire" or userChoice == "fire" and compChoice == "water":
        print("You lose!")
        compScore += 1
        print("Scores: User: %d CPU: %d" %(userScore, compScore))
    elif userChoice == "quit":
        print("Final scores: User: %d CPU: %d" %(userScore, compScore))
        print("Thanks for playing!")
```

I added to the while loop to make a condition that whoever get their score to match the max score, the game should end.

Comment: And what exactly is your question? Does your code show any errors or unexpected behavior? Please edit your question and add more details about what you expect to see and what actually happens. Add enough details so that we can reproduce your issue with only the information in your question.

Comment: Look at your condition on the `while`: `userChoice != "quit"` is true, and if any term on an `or` is true, the whole condition is true. So you never exit the loop until the user enters "quit". You probably need to rewrite the loop condition as `userChoice != "quit" and userScore != targetScore and compScore != targetScore:`

Comment: Although I think the question overall was clear enough, you did have the question hidden away in the title and the text of the question only stated what you wanted. Try to pick a short and descriptive title, and always explain the problem and the actual question clearly in the text of the question. (Welcome to StackOverflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `while` condition:

```
while userChoice != "quit" or userScore == targetScore or compScore == targetScore:
```

So, as long as the user chose something other than `'quit'`, keep playing. Or as long as the `userScore` is the `targetScore`, also keep playing. Or as long as the `compScore` is the `targetScore`, keep playing.

You want the opposite for the latter two conditions. It seems that you want the game to end if the user enters `'quit'` or if either score reaches the `targetScore`.

Something like:

```
userChoice == 'quit' or userScore == targetScore or compScore == targetScore
```

If this is *not* true, the game needs to keep going, so:

```
while not (userChoice == 'quit' or userScore == targetScore or compScore == targetScore):
```

Thanks to Boolean logic, this can be rewritten to (and this is probably what you aimed for):

```
while userChoice != 'quit' and userScore != targetScore and compScore != targetScore:
```

However, I think the expression with `not` is clearer (and it's equivalent).

Just a note: the convention for naming variables in Python is 'snake_case', avoiding the use of capitals. Although it's a style choice, it makes your code easier to read by others, and easier to combine with the code of others - you would do well to adopt the standard early on. (have a look at [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) if you're interested)

Comment: A simple and condition would work and arguably be more readable.